# get a single element of a list from replace

Tags: replacement

`Replace[x, {{x -> a}, {x -> b},{y->c}}]` gives `{a,b,x}`. How to get just `{a,b}` from the above expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use this for a more general case.  Knowing what the general case is would help me know which solution would be generalizable to your situation.

One way is to use ReplaceList with Flatten:

```
Flatten[ReplaceList[x, {{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {y -> c}}]]
```

Or more simply:

```
ReplaceList[x, {x -> a, x -> b, y -> c}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra replacement to each list such that if nothing matches you return `Nothing`

```
nullrep = _ :> Nothing
(* _ :> Nothing *)

Replace[x, {{x -> a, nullrep}, {x -> b, nullrep}, {y -> c, nullrep}}]
(* {a, b} *)
```